# 'Solver' object has no attribute 'Intvar' in google or-tools

Tags: python, optimization, attributes, or-tools

```
import numpy as np
!pip install ortools
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')
#DECISIONVARIABLES
infinity = solver.infinity()
x = solver.Intvar(0.0, infinity, 'x')
y = solver.Intvar(0.0, 1.0, 'x')
```

for the above program I am getting the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [15], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 #DECISIONVARIABLES
      2 infinity = solver.infinity()
----> 3 x = solver.Intvar(0.0, infinity, 'x')
      4 y = solver.Intvar(0.0, 1.0, 'x')

AttributeError: 'Solver' object has no attribute 'Intvar'
```

What might be the problem here?

Comment: `IntVar` rather than `Intvar`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Intvar attribute name with "IntVar":

```
import numpy as np
!pip install ortools
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')
#DECISIONVARIABLES
infinity = solver.infinity()
x = solver.Intvar(0.0, infinity, 'x')
y = solver.Intvar(0.0, 1.0, 'x')
```